# Alguém sabe o porque o Select do MySQL as vezes não Funciona?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou enfrentando um problema, no qual eu tenho uma tabela no BD e ela contém os dados. Porém quando eu faço o `SELECT`, alguns dados ela retorna e outros não.
Por exemplo:

Na tabela `Codigos` eu tenho os seguintes dados.

```
|idEquipamento|idCodigo|
|      1      |  123   |
|      2      | abc123 |
```

E quando eu faço o `select` um retorna resultado e outro não:

```
"SELECT idEquipamento, idCodigo FROM Codigos WHERE idCodigo = 123";
```

Retorna resultado!

```
"SELECT idEquipamento, cdCodigo FROM Codigos WHERE idCodigo = 'abc123'";
```

Não retorna nenhum registro, como se não existisse. Mas quando abro a tabela os dados estão lá, consigo editar e tudo!

Obs.: Estou fazendo o `SELECT` pelo próprio phpMyAdmin!

Comment: o `idCodigo` é um varchar ou int? veja que os campos que vc busca na consulta não estão na tabela da pergunta, vide `Codigo` e `cdCodigo`.

Comment: Desculpa escrevi errado na pergunta mas os campos de where no caso são: WHERE idCodigo = 123; e WHERE idCodigo = 'abc123';

Sim eles são VARCHAR!

Comment: @JonatasM Se você escreveu algo errado, edite a pergunta para evitar confundir os demais usuários que vierem a responder.

Comment: Como são varchars, pode ser tenham sido gravados com espaço da um `trim()` para garantir e lembre de usar aspas simples nos valores.

Comment: O que um `SELECT * FROM eq_Codigos` retorna? Por que você tem `Codigos` e `eq_Codigos`? Qual é a diferença entre essas duas tabelas?

Comment: Desculpa estava corrigindo a pergunta pois, os dois select são na mesma tabela, ele simplesmente retorna:  MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (A consulta demorou 0.0094 segundos.)

Comment: Pra tirar a dúvida vc poderia pegar o create da sua tabela e alguns inserts e testar no sqlfiddle aí coloca o link aqui, isso vai eleminar o problema de ambiente se ele existir.

Comment: Cara eu não sei o que é sqlfiddle e nem como us-alo! vou dar uma pesquisada sobre isso!

Comment: Na segunda consulta é `cdCodigo` ou `idCodigo`?

Comment: Qual é o nome do seu banco de dados?

Comment: faça o select sem o where copie o teste que você e user ele no where da forma que ele esta retornando e veja o que tem de estranho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabela: **Codigos** (com **C** maiúsculo)

```
|idEquipamento|idCodigo|
|      1      |  123   |
|      2      | abc123 |
```

Teste esse comando:

```
SELECT idEquipamento, idCodigo FROM Codigos WHERE idCodigo = 'abc123'
```

Ele deverá retorna a segunda linha.
Depois testes mais esses 2 comandos para ver o que retorna:

```
SELECT idEquipamento, idCodigo FROM Codigos WHERE idCodigo = '123'

SELECT * FROM Codigos WHERE idCodigo = 'abc123'
```

Tente também com `TRIM()`

```
SELECT * FROM Codigos WHERE TRIM(idCodigo) = 'abc123'
```

Comment: Então, quando eu busco pelo idCodigo 123 ele retorna a primeira linha normal, só que quando eu busco pelo idCodigo abc123, ele aparece a mensagem:
MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (A consulta demorou 0.0094 segundos.)

Comment: Testou os outros 2 comandos que coloquei ?

Comment: Sim Sim Testei! Inclusive eu já testei até usando o LIKE no lugar do =

Comment: @JonatasM adicionei mais um comando lá com `TRIM()` veja se retorna algum resultado

Comment: Acabei de testar, ele da a mesma mensagem: MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (A consulta demorou 0.0018 segundos.)

Comment: @JonatasM se for possível, clica em `Exportar` no seu MySQL e exporta o arquivo .SQL e cola o conteúdo dela em sua pergunta, assim podemos fazer testes aqui em nosso MySQ. Fazendo isso me avise aqui.

Comment: Tenta usar o like e me diga se o resultado aparece: SELECT idEquipamento, idCodigo FROM Codigos WHERE idCodigo like '%abc123%'

Comment: Exporte o banco de dados para termos uma melhor visualização do problema e resolve-ló

Comment: Então, descobri que na hora que eu faço o insert no BD, ele vai com um "/r" no final do insert.
Mas não estou conseguindo fazer o tratamento da variável no php para não inserir com essa informação no BD!

Comment: Veja se um `str_replace()` funciona.. Tipo `$conteudo = str_replace("/r", "". $conteudo_aqui);`

Answer (score 0):

Quando tu usa o `where` é o mesmo que falar quando.

Em `Where idCodigo = 'abc123`', tu só vai puxar a linha onde a coluna `idCodigo` for igual a `'abc123'`, se quiser as duas linhas tira o `where`